# how to generate sound of exact frequecy in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, frequency

I want to create a project in JavaScript in which I want to generate sounds of all frequency from 20 to 20K. is there any way to do ?
I have used http://codebase.es/riffwave/ this library also but if I select frequency of sound greater than 20K db, I am still hearing that. so this js library is not accurate according to my need.
can you suggest some way in achieving my task.

Comment: Can you explain your problem more clearly? If you only want frequencies in the range from 20 Hz to 20 kHz, why does it matter if riffwave is unable to produce sounds outside this range? Also, I suggest you learn about [Nyquist frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) and how they relate to whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The Web Audio API can be used to generate sounds.
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001552/ch04.html#s04_5

Comment: Yes, and for Firefox, you can use playbackRate and preservePitch="false"

Comment: Chris Wilson shows some of the capabilities of the Web Audio API in his [presentation](http://html5devconf.com/archives/april2013/sessions.html#c_wilson) at HTML5 Developer Conference if you want to learn more.